# Working around segmentation faults using parfor loops in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, segmentation-fault, mex

I am currently working on a project where I have to run multiple repetitions of a time-consuming MATLAB function in parallel. For the purposes of this question, let's refer to the function as `myfunc`.

`myfunc` uses a MEX file and ends up with a random segmentation violation once every 3 hours. I cannot diagnose the segmentation fault since it originates from a propriety API that I did not code myself. However, I do know that it occurs within the MEX file, and I also know that it is not deterministically related to any settings I can change.

I would like to work around the segmentation violation, and I would ideally also like to keep on using the parfor function in MATLAB. My idea right now is to use a try catch loop within the parfor loop as follows:

```
    %create an output cell to store nreps of output from 'myfunc'
    output = cell(1,nreps) 

    %create a vector to keep track of how many runs finish successfully without the error
    successfulrun = zeros(1,nreps);

    % run myfunc in parallel
    parfor i = 1:nreps
       try
        output{i}
        successfulrun(i) = true
       end
    end

    %rerun experiments that did not end up successfully
    while sum(successulruns) < nreps

      %count number of experiments to rerun and initialize variables to hold those results
      reps_to_rerun = find(successfulruns == 0);
      nreps_to_rerun = sum(reps_to_rerun);
      newoutput = cell(1,nreps_to_rerun);
      newsuccessfulrun = zeros(1,nreps_to_rerun)

      %rerun experiments
      parfor i = 1:nreps_to_rerun
         try
          newoutput{i};  
          newsuccessfulrun = true;  
         end  
      end

     %transfer contents to larger loop
     for i = 1:nreps_to_rerun

        rerun_index =  reps_to_rerun(i);
        successfulrun(rerun_index) = newsuccessfulrun(i)

        if newsuccessfulrun(i)
            output{i} = newoutput{i};
        end 
    end
end
```

My questions are:

1. Will it be OK to keep continuing to run more repetitions like this even though there was a segmentation violation within the MEX file? Or should I clear the memory / restart the matlabpool? I'm assuming this shouldn't be problem since the segmentation violation was in C.
2. Is there any way to "break" out of a parfor loop?

Comment: Segfault will either crash MATLAB, or stop the code and give you an option to try to continue, which you should only do to try to save your data. You will not get an exception. There is no way around this other than fixing the illegal memory access.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t break out of a parfor loop because it isn’t running in serial. For this reason, parfor loops can’t be nested.^1

If you’re running out of space, you should increase your JVM memory allocation limit.^2

Works cited:

1. https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:MinlgB0S8fsJ:its2.unc.edu/divisions/rc/training/scientific/short_courses/ParallelGPUMATLAB.pptx+&hl=en&gl=us&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEEShtEaahOf7u01kO0vT-Asy8itHNzuo4xocdoM5kiAuSCWlHZlKKb-W3Lvftpd6HJJAeyp6Lt-ofaBVH1uG049DFuAzdiu4ElNCtiTeFfYYbSGsJN5JF4S-AKjmWnmIpWIRNHHnR&sig=AHIEtbRU7F2iX9rPnaZBXux3ewL42VCIZQ
2. http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parfor.html